# how to align horizontal list inside div?

Tags: css

i am trying to center my horizontal <ul> inside a <div> (the yellow stripe in my example). the markup is below. i know that if <li> were not floated then i could do it by setting left and right margins on <ul> to "auto", but i do not seem to find a way to get rid of "float" because i need my <li> be block elements so that i could size them. please help!
thanks
konstantin

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container
        {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        .container li
        {
            border: solid 1px grey;
            display: block;
            float: left;
            height: 100px;
            line-height: 100px;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">x</a></li>
            <li><div>y</div></li>
        </ul>
        <div style="clear: both;">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Demo posted, on OP's behalf, at: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/onozu5).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is a block level element, and so takes up the entire width of container... also text-align is for aligning text.  You could do something like:

```
.container ul{
    width:400px;
    margin:0px auto
}
```

Comment: thanks. this works. i would prefer to not use fixed width because in general my &lt;ul> is auto-generated and can contain variable amount of items.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, works on firefox and chrome

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    .container
    {
        background-color: yellow;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .container ul
    {
        display: inline-table;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .container li
    {
        border: solid 1px grey;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 100px;
        line-height: 100px;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">x</a></li>
        <li>
            <div>
                y</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear: both;">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to answer your question because I can't even see the yellow stripe in FF 3.6.8

but have a look at this http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/ - there are many options and it might help you out.